# stop synonyms.txt file Solr from being stemmed

Tags: solr, solrcloud, synonym, stemming

In synonyms.txt file I have an entry
`marine => saltwater,marine` but both the words are getting stemmed to `'saltwat', 'marin'` respectively inspite of being in protected words file. Is there a way to avoid it?

schema.xml

```
 <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" analyzer="org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

synonyms.txt

```
marine => saltwater,marine
```

protwords.txt

```
saltwater
marine
```

now when I do the analysis in admin panel and query for `saltwat` then `saltwat | marin` comes up. which means that saltwater did get stemmed to `saltwat` in synonyms.txt file 
[image: saltwat | marin]

Comment: shrare your schema.xml for this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solr analysis works in the same sequence you declare it inside your fieldType definition in schema. So, if you declare any Stem filter after the Synonyms filter, it will be applied after the synonyms changes. If you don't want this, the SynonymsFilter should be configured after the StemFilter, for example:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I recommend you to check [Solr Analysis](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/analysis-screen.html) tool in your Solr Admin to check what's going on with your field in both indexing and querying time.

Please share your schema if you need more help.

Comment: I have added all the files necessary. Kindly have a look.

Comment: That's because you're using org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer in your synonym filter config. It's responsible for applying stemming too. Try removing the analyzer from your Synonym filter config (I've updated the answer to match your config).

Comment: Yes English analyzer is needed as it handles a lot of inputs BUT I see that there are 3 constructors in https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.html so is there a way I can use the third one in my schema to which I can pass stemExclusionSet to stop words from getting stemmed inside synonyms.txt

Comment: It looks like you can't change the analyser config at this time: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Configuring-a-custom-Analyzer-for-the-SynonymFilter-td4298257.html. What you can ever do is to build your own analyser, pack it as a custom lib in solr and reference it in your synonym config. In this case you can just extend the EnglishAnalyser and configure what you want to change. BUT.. Are you sure you really need to analyse the synonyms?

Comment: Yes I need to analyze the synonyms as I do not want to enter plurals for all the entries in my synonyms file. what do you mean by "pack it as custom library in solr"?

Comment: I mean you can write your own analyser... I didn't do that yet with an analyser, but in theory it's something like this: write your java class that extends the EnglishAnalyser and calls the constructor you want, pack it in a jar file, include that jar in solr contrib folder, reference that jar as a <lib /> in your solrconfig.xml, and reference your analyser class (fully qualified class name) in the synonymFilter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Protwords (protected words) are words that would be stemmed by the
English porter stemmer that you do not want to be stemmed.

A customized protected word list may be specified with the "protected" attribute in the schema. Any words in the protected word list will not be modified by any stemmer in Solr.

```
<fieldtype name="myfieldtype" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

Comment: I have added all the files necessary. Kindly have a look.